# FTP issue from Linux to windows server through shell script

Tags: linux, ftp, patch, suse, lftp

We are having an automated .ksh script transfer the files from Linux server to windows server

The ftp commands used are:

```
Cd /target/sieb //path in local Linux server 

ftp -inv $ftpserv

user $FTPUSER $FTPPW

cd /sieb/app

mput sgt*.*
```

This script is failing with error: ftp:local: sgt*.* no such file or directory found error.

This script is running without any issue for so many years,but failing after the Linux OS patching.On checking with OS team,we were informed that Suse 12 os version is pointing to lftp by default and previously it is pftp

I am not much familiar with ftp commands.Any suggetions to resolve the issue will be helpful.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Give the full path to the ftp program you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The path mentioned is the full path only and script is running fine with same commands since so many years.The only change was done on Linux server was that pftp was changed to lftp.So could you please suggest if any script level changes or server level changes to resolve the issue?